# Adding attendees to android calendar event

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-calendar

I have managed to pass through the "main" information into a calendar intent...

however when I try to add attendees to the intent, they are not inserted. Here is the code

```
        startCalIntent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        startCalIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

        startCalIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
        startCalIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
        startCalIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, details);
        startCalIntent.putExtra(Events.ORGANIZER, organiser);
        startCalIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, splitDateTime(date, startTime));
        startCalIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, splitDateTime(date, endTime));
        startCalIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/London");


        startCalIntent.putExtra(Attendees.HAS_ATTENDEE_DATA, "1"); 
        startCalIntent.putExtra(Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "DAVE");//<---NOT WORKING

        startActivity(startCalIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add attendee during creating event. You need Event_ID to proceed another update on event like adding remainders, or attendees.

> Note: See how this example captures the event ID after the event is
>   created. This is the easiest way to get an event ID. You often need
>   the event ID to perform other calendar operations—for example, to add
>   attendees or reminders to an event.

source: [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event)

you can use this code as provided in Android developer:

```
long eventID = 202;
...
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "Trevor");
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, "trevor@example.com");
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ATTENDEE);
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE, Attendees.TYPE_OPTIONAL);
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED);
values.put(Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventID);
Uri uri = cr.insert(Attendees.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Hope that may help;

Answer (score -2):

Try this ..

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", "event Name");
values.put("allDay", 0);
values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis() + diffInhrs*60*1000); // event starts at date specified in datepicker
values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+ end_diff *60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from selected date
values.put("description", "event desc");
values.put("visibility", 0);
values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
```

For more explaination plz go through this [CLICK HERE](http://vaibhavadhyapak.blogspot.in/2012/05/you-need-to-make-separate-class-i.html)